# There is difference in behaviour when an instance variable is computed instead of being stored

Tags: ios, swift, getter-setter, iboutlet

I have a custom `UIView` class that is initiated from the `xib` file. It has instance property called `title` of type `String?`. Whenever, the `title` property is set, the text of a `UITextField` gets changed to the value of the `title` property.

If the `title` property is a stored property, the program works as expected.

If the `title` property is a computed property, then the program crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error which I assume is because an `IBOutlet` had not yet been initialized.

Can anyone explain why if `title` is a stored property, it works but if it is an computed property it fails?

Following is the source code-
The `NibView` is a subclass of `UIView` and handles the loading of xib file

```
class NibView: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        loadNib()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        loadNib()
    }
}
```

The implementation of `loadNib` method is inside an extension

```
extension UIView {
    func loadNib() {
        guard let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView else { return }

        view.frame = bounds
        addSubview(view)
    }
}
```

The definition of `nib` property on `UIView` is in another extension

```
extension UIView {
    static var nib: UINib {
        return UINib(nibName: String(describing: self), bundle: nil)
    }

    var nib: UINib {
        return type(of: self).nib
    }
}
```

The following class is the class which has the title property.

```
class ProgressView: NibView {
    var title: String? {
        didSet {
            titleLabel.text = title
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet private weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
}
```

The above class is used as follows-

```
let view = ProgressView()
addSubview(view)
view.title = "Loading"
```

Running the above code works as expected.
However if the implementation of `ProgressView` is changed to use a computed property as below, then it fails

```
class ProgressView: NibView {
    var title: String? {
        get {
            return titleLabel.text
        }
        set {
            titleLabel.text = newValue
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet private weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
}
```

Can anyone point out why where is difference in behaviour when the `title` property is computed instead of being stored?

Edit - 
The main thread crashes with "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)"

The method on top of the call stack is "ProgressView.title.modify".

Edit 2- 
I am not sure what I have done but I am unable to reproduce the issue after restarting xcode. Even if computed property is used, it works as expected.

Comment: What happens if you change your `get` to `return titleLabel?.text ?? ""`

Comment: just `return titleLabel?.text` should suffice since `title` is `String?`

Comment: *"which I assume is because"* - Run your code in the debugger and see what's actually happening instead of making an assumption. Update your question with what you find.

Comment: FYI - when you use a stored property, nothing is being done with the getter. The getter may not reflect the actual value in the label. That's not related to the issue but it's a big difference between the stored property version and the computed value version.

Comment: You should add breakpoints to all the where you are creating the ProgressView and all the lines where you get and set the Computed property. I’d do it in Xcode but I’m on my iPhone at the moment. It’ll be very informative as to what exactly is causing this error. It’d also be great if you included the name of the error printed in the console/debugger. If this question hasn’t been answered by the time I get my computer charged, I’ll try and figure it out.

Comment: @vacawama It does not make any difference if `get` returns `titleLabel?.text` instead of `titleLabel.text`. The program still crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is far from explanatory, but I'm guessing that there is a ProgressView nib in which the File's Owner is a ProgressView, and there is an `titleLabel` outlet from the File's owner to a label inside the nib. (I assume this because otherwise I can't explain your use of `withOwner: self`.)

On that assumption I can't reproduce any problem. Both your ways of expressing `title` work just fine for me. I put `print` statements to make sure the right one was being called, and it is; no matter whether this is a `didSet` or the setter of a computed property, we load just fine and I see the "Loading" text.

My code is in a view controller's `viewDidLoad`, if that makes a difference.

(By the way, I regard your use of `ProgressView()` with suspicion. This results in a zero-size view. It might not seem to make any difference, but it's a bad idea. The label is a subview of the zero-size view. If the zero-size view clipped its subviews, the label would be invisible. Even if the zero-size view does not clip its subviews, if the label were a button, the button would not work. Zero-size views are a bad idea. You should give your ProgressView a real frame.)

Comment: If that doesn't help, please make a _minimal complete verifiable example_ project and post it so that I can see where your setup differs from mine.

Comment: You are correct on how I have setup my custom UIView. The code for custom UIView is adapted from https://medium.com/swift2go/swift-custom-uiview-with-xib-file-211bb8bbd6eb . I am unable to reproduce the issue that I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: If you can't reproduce your own issue, then the matter is closed, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. the matter is closed.

Comment: Regarding the zero-size view issue mentioned in the answer, I failed to mention in my question that I added autolayout constraints.

Comment: Excellent, that makes sense. And of course the subview should be pinned by constraints to the superview when it is loaded and added.

Comment: I would also like to add that the use of the second UIView extension is overblown and confusing. Everything can be succinctly and clearly stated right in the `loadNib` implementation.